# are there a javascript or lodash function that makes it easy to iterate through pairs or triples

Tags: javascript, iterator

so I want to fill in the every(#) here:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

arr.every(2)(function(a,b) {
  return a + b;
})

// [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]

arr.every(3)(function(a,b,c) {
  return a + b + c;
})

// [6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the reduce function:

```
arr.reduce(function(p,v,i,a) { if( i + 1 < a.length ) p.push( a[i] + a[i + 1] ); return p; },[]);
arr.reduce(function(p,v,i,a) { if( i + 2 < a.length ) p.push( a[i] + a[i + 1] + a[i + 2]); return p; },[]);
```

I would not override the array prototype lightly.  If you want a function that does every:

```
every = function(a,n,c) { return a.reduce(function(p,v,i,a) { if( i + n - 1 < a.length ) p.push( c.apply( this, a.slice( i, i + n ) ) ); return p; }, [] ); };

every(arr,2,function(a,b){return a+b;});
every(arr,3,function(a,b,c){return a+b+c;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically you can just assign the jump variable in the interval you want: `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2)`. You can bump that `2` to anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method available in java script . you have to implement one by yourself.by extending array's prototype.

there is already a method in javascript named "every" which will be used to find whether all elements are  satisfying some condition.

so use different name or caps or underscore to avoid overriding.

Edited as per your requirement

```
Array.prototype._every = function (n, callback) {

             if ( n > this.length ) 
                 return new Error("Invalid pair size"); 

             var everyEl = new Array(this.length - (n - 1)),result = []; 

             var original = this, temp = new Array(n);

             original.forEach(function (val, ind) {

                   if ( (ind + 1) >= n ) {
                      result[ ind-n ] = callback.apply(this, original.slice(n - ind - 1, ind, n));    
                   } 

             });

            return result;

   }

you should call this method like this

var arr = [10,20,30,40];

arr._every(2, function(a, b){
     return a+b;
});
```

Comment: i think what you have is a truncation of the original array. where as I am expecting  Array#_every 2 to be executed 3 times on [10, 20] [20, 30] [30, 40], in other words all adjacence.